# How can I make a gameObject jump quick at first then start slowing down after a while?

Tags: unity, c#, animation

How can I make a gameObject jump quick at first then start slowing down after a while? It definitely has something to do with deltaTime.

Comment: Is there a rigidbody on the object?

Comment: Yes, a rigibody is attached to the object.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the drag continuously after the player had jumped so that your object slows down. Or increasing the gravity?

Comment: Using drag might be ok, since it is unique per object. Changing the gravity will affect all objects in the scene though.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the gravity on the Rigidbody and then just make gravity yourself by writing a script and using `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(-Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * YOUR GRAVITY VALUE)` and just change YOUR GRAVITY VALUE when ever you want the object to be slowed down.

Comment: +1 There we go. This explains how to apply gravity correctly to a single object. I do think that drag might be more appropriate though, if you want it to slow down in the horizontal direction as well. Otherwise you'd need to adjust the vector to match the jump trajectory.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, applying gravity to a specific rigidbody will not effect everything in the scene. If it does, then you have a larger issue about to come. Calling a reference to the rigidbody attactched to an object and adding gravity * Time.deltaTime will increase gravity until the player touches back down. At that point I would decide a max gravity value to be applied so when it's hit, it will not cause the object to come crashing down. Instead start reducing gravity until it touches down then reset gravity back to its starting value.

Edit: I'd suggest the possibility of using a switch and assigning transforms to bools as to set specific increments to gravity so on the way down it recheck the transforms again and reduce gravity.

Comment: AFAIK the rigidbody component does not have it's own gravity. you would have to disable gravity and then apply a force to simulate gravity, otherwise all rigidbodys with gravity enabled will be affected when you change Physics.gravity.

Comment: Partially right. You disable gravity and you go rigidbody.AddForce (Physics.gravity)